# Robust parameter optimization optimizing profit using clustering, classification or regression?

Tags: regression, classification, clustering, optimization, scikit-learn

Imagine an algorithm with a parameter applied to different applications. For each application and parameter I can estimate the performance of the algorithm using simulations and historic data.
Therefore, I have a matrix of size `number of applications` times `number of parameters` with the associated profits. There are about 300 different applications.
Now if I would fully trust the estimates, I could - for each application - use the parameter maximizing profit. However, this is probably over-fitting, as the quality of data for different applications differs.

**Example**: Imagine selling different fruits (applications) and increasing/decreasing the price by X percent (parameters), then estimating the resulting overall profit using customer profiles. The daily profits per application (fruit) would look something like this

|  | 5% decrease in price | no change | 5% increase in price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| avocados | 8000€ | 8500€ | 10500€ |
| bananas | 5500€ | 5000€ | 4300€ |
| oranges | 7000€ | 7100€ | 6900€ |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

**How can I confirm the results using additional features I have regarding the applications?**
In the example, the features could be the original price of the fruits, the weight, the buying price, the number of daily sales...

I see three different approaches:

1. Unsupervised learning: Cluster the applications using similar features and test the performance per cluster per parameter. For example, this could group expensive fruits that one seldomly buys and where the price could matter less. However, this completely ignores the estimated profits while clustering.
2. Classification: Estimate the best parameter for each application. Then train a classifier on the additional features and test the classification. **However, 'accuracy' is kind of a bad estimator for performance here**, because I care less about a misclassification of oranges than avocados (less price difference). I would want to maximize resulting price instead of classification accuracy. Should I touch the loss/scoring function?
3. Regression: As the price increase/decrease can be almost continuous (e.g. +-5% in 1% steps), one could also let the algorithm perform a regression task instead of a classification. This could help finding the maximum.

Any help would be appreciated, feel free to ask questions and suggest approaches to validate the simulation/estimates and maximize performance/profit. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean with confirming the results? Would you reword this as, how might I improve the results using additional features for each product group?

Comment: The results of the simulation based on the historic data are error-prone, mainly due to noise. Imagine that all fruit prices have been de-/increased for different amounts of time and the results may be more or less significant. How can I best validate the results of the simulation? I want to identify groups of fruits that have similar features and behave similar in the simulation. Additionally, I would want to detect outliers that behave way different than similar fruits.